Difference in wording in narrations
It was mentioned in a previous post clarifying a report by anas ibn malik ra in sunan al kubra al beyhaqi 2/320 that the slave girls of umar ra were serving with their hair uncovered and hitting their breasts and the confusion arose from the word تَضْرِبُ  which was used to denote "strikes or hits" however this narration was reworded to تَضْطَرِبُ which denotes "shakes" changing the meaning to "serving with their hair uncovered and breasts shaking" in Book of Knowledge of Sunnah and Athar 3/146 (4071) authored by beyhaqi as well. What accounts for the difference in wording and which is the correct narration?
https://shamela.ws/book/2863/1247
https://shamela.ws/book/7861/3655

Please consider adding at least a link to the post you are referring to and possibly the content you are referring to, so that a potential answerer could find all necessary information in your post.

@Medi1Saif done
